# Java reading in sections of a string

Tags: java, string, input

So I'm trying to write a program where it reads in parts of a string per each line. For example the user can input:

```
Item car small
Item toy big
```

which comes across as this:

```
Item <item name> <size>
```

Basically, with this information, I store it into the program, so that whenever the user whats to access it later they can call it. The first string `car`indicates to the program, that the user is storing another item into the database. My question is, how do I read the input so that I can grab each section of the string `item` `<item name>` and `<size>`.

Comment: The key word you looking for is "parse". You want to parse the input.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`split`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) method:

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
String wholeLine = scan.nextLine();
String[] tokens = whileLine.split();
```

now `token[0]` should be `"Item"`, `token[1]` should be `"car"` and `token[2]` should be `"small"`, if the user inputs `Item car small`

Answer (score 1):

```
for(Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("my-input-file.txt")); sc.hasNext(); ) {
  String[] words = sc.nextLine().split(" ");
  String itemName = words[1];
  String size = words[2];
  // Now store itemName, size in the DB...     
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Read a each line with readLine() method and then use StringTokenizer to get tokens out of it.